Google compute engine debian instance boots to emergency mode
I have a debian 12 instance which was working fine but now gets stuck in emergency mode after a reboot.
The serial port output


[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mnetwork-online.target[0m - Network is Online.


[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mnss-lookup.…m - Host and Network Name Lookups.


You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view

system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"

to boot into default mode.



Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

See sulogin(8) man page for more details.



Looking through the serial port logs, there are no "error" logs, but a fs related job times out.  I'm guessing this is the attached zfs disk (non root).
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3277db\x2…tart running (1min 28s / 1min 30s)
M
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3277db\x2…tart running (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
M
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3277db\x2…tart running (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
M
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6b3277db\x2…tart running (1min 30s / 1min 30s)
M
[K[[0;1;31m TIME [0m] Timed out waiting for device [0;1;…277db-5548-43c1-8dd5-179c5c2e4dae.
[K[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39msyst…277db-5548-43c1-8dd5-179c5c2e4dae.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mmedi…ta\x2d1.mount[0m - /media/data-1.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mloca…s.target[0m - Local File Systems.

The first time this happened it was due to a "shielded_vm_integrity" event;
lateBootReportEvent: {
   actualMeasurements: [11]
   policyEvaluationPassed: false
   policyMeasurements: [3]
}

I have now disabled vTPM, Integrity Monitoring & Secure Boot options.  I no longer get the integrity event, however the machine still goes to emergency mode.
I would like to recover this instance if possible.  Any ideas on how to address?  Even connect to the console would be a step in the right direction.
